# Stay or Leave. Promotion Offered to Stay

Tags: new-job, promotion

I'm a senior developer at a fairly large company.  I've been in the industry 10 years, all with the same company.  I've had two positions both lasting ~5 years.  The last couple of large projects have gone pretty badly, causing the dev team to work nights and weekends prior to golive.  Our current project seems to be in a much better place, and over all things seem to be improving.  I started sending my resume out ~ 6 months ago for internal positions because of my frustrations with the last project executions and because I didn't think my manager was interested in advancing my career.  I've interviewed and verbally accepted an offer for another position in my current company that would be a promotion and salary increase of about 10%.  When I told my current manager this, he said "I didn't know you were actively looking at other positions, we were actually trying to open up a position for you on the team".  Either way it would be the same promotion and title.

I like my current team, I like mentoring the junior guys on our team and developing the apps we work on.  On the other hand I think I would enjoy the work at the new position as well.  I have more flexibility at my current job than I would initially under the new manager (partially working from home etc).  On top of this, my wife is pregnant and we are expecting a baby in ~5 months.  I believe my manager when he said they were going to open a position for me to be promoted, He's trustworthy but I didn't know he valued me this much.  He's also been out of the office on medical leave for the past few months, so I'm not sure that caused the delay or lack of communication on his part.

UGH, what should I do?  New job, or stay and wait ~1-2 months for the same promotion...?

Comment: This is a "what should I do" question that only can be answered by yourself. But imagine you taking a new job and things don't turn out the way you hoped, can you still provide for your family?

Comment: I wouldn't be so naive about trusting that your boss was planning on promoting you already. Likely he found out that you were going to move to another team so he backpedaled and made it seem like they were already going to do this for you. Yes you should have come to him first inquiring about a promotion as he might have opened it up to you even before knowing you would leave if you didn't get it. If you stay, as the answer says, your boss will always wonder if you're going to jump ship again at the prospect of a better offer. Next time see if there's opportunity for promotion within before.

Comment: Make a list of what you value the most in a job, and arrange it in priority order. Then choose.

Comment: You don't mention where you're located. If in the UK, then you will only get statutory paternity leave if you've worked there for >12 months.   This may be a consideration.  (as a senior dev, statutory paternity *pay* is probably not a consideration...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say you can only play this card ( counter offer ) once if you stay at your current company.

Consider these points:

1. Your boss most likely will always wonder when will he give notice again.
2. What were your reasons for seeking other employment?  Have those reasons gone away?  If not, move on.
3. If layoffs were to occur at your current company, and you stay after accepting a counter offer, you could be at the top of the list of those who go.
4. Its always best to leave a company on your terms

In short, I generally do not accept counter offers ( my current company matches ).  However, if a promotion is offered, that would be different.

Comment: They are both positions in my current company.  It would be a promotion/transfer if I took the new position, or just a promotion if I stay in my current team.

Comment: Oh, same company -- missed that!  In that case I say why not take it?

Comment: My main reason for applying elsewhere was the fact that I didn't think my current manager would advance my career, but now he claims that he was intending to in the very near term.  Also, just general nerves about starting a new position in a new team.  Lots of unknowns in the new team.

Comment: @cobolstinks Yes, now that you have taken action, of course he "was intending to in the near term" -- If you leave, it will inconvenience and possibly reflect poorly on him, so there is a measure of self-preservation in his words.It's not necessarily that he has your best interest at heart. I recently went through a similar situation -- just my 2 cents.

Comment: Why the downvote?  In what way is this answer not useful?

Comment: Ok yeah, almost all my colleagues think I should move on, and I just called my current manager to resign.  In the end the only reason I have to stay is that I'm comfortable where I'm at, but I think that's also the best reason to move.